# Vector of std::function<>

Tags: c++, function, hash, c++11

Say want to store the following:

```
typedef std::function<void(int)> MyFunctionDecl;
```

..in a collection:

```
typedef std::vector<MyFunctionDecl> FunctionVector;
FunctionVector v;
```

This is possible, but if I want to *find* something using `std::find`:

```
FunctionVector::const_iterator cit = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), myFunctionDecl);
```

.. we get an error due to the `==` operator.

As has been suggested to me in a previous question concerning this, this can be gotten around by encapsulating the function declaration within another class, which provides a `==` operator:

```
class Wrapper
{
private:
    MyFunctionDecl m_Func;

public:
    // ctor omitted for brevity

    bool operator == (const Wrapper& _rhs)
    {
         // are they equal?
    }; // eo ==
};  // eo class Wrapper
```

So what I want to do is somehow generate a hash for "MyFunctionDecl" so that I can properly implement the `==` operator.  I could have some kind of unique identifier, and ask the caller to provide a unique identifier for the delegate, but this seems a bit of a pain and is error prone.

Is there a way that I can do this?  So that the same functions will return the same ID for comparative purposes?  So far, the only way around it is to dump the notion of using `std::function` and go back to using fast delegates which support comparisons.  But then I lose the ability to use lambdas.

Any help appreciated!

**EDIT**

Given the answer below, this is what I have come up with...  any caveats I might have missed?  I'm in the process of putting it through it's paces now:

```
class MORSE_API Event : boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void(const EventArgs&)> DelegateType;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<DelegateType> DelegateDecl;

private:
    typedef std::set<DelegateDecl> DelegateSet;
    typedef DelegateSet::const_iterator DelegateSet_cit;
    DelegateSet m_Delegates;

public:
    Event()
    {
    };  // eo ctor


    Event(Event&& _rhs) : m_Delegates(std::move(_rhs.m_Delegates))
    {
    };  // eo mtor

    ~Event()
    {
    };  // eo dtor

    // methods
    void invoke(const EventArgs& _args)
    {
        std::for_each(m_Delegates.begin(),
                      m_Delegates.end(),
                      [&_args](const DelegateDecl& _decl) { (*_decl)(_args); });
    };  // eo invoke

    DelegateDecl addListener(DelegateType f)
    {
        DelegateDecl ret(new DelegateType(f));
        m_Delegates.insert(ret);
        return ret;
    };  // eo addListener

    void removeListener(const DelegateDecl _decl)
    {
        DelegateSet_cit cit(m_Delegates.find(_decl));
        if(cit != m_Delegates.end())
            m_Delegates.erase(cit);
    };  // eo removeListener

};  // eo class Event
```

Comment: Why do you need to find? If you need to find a std::function like this, you will need to find it based on some identifier or similar, say an automatically generated int for each new Wrapper you create. Get the int for future comparison and make sure that you only create each wrapper once.

Comment: You cannot compare functions, this is the *halting problem* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem )

Comment: @Alexandre I think the halting problem is related but definitely not the same. I would think that the idea of the hash is that you don't need to run the function to compare it.

Comment: @villintehaspam, Adding and iterating is not a problem.  However, want to create an event-type class that allows multiple delegates to be stored and, if they so desire, to remove themselves also.  Think of `addListener` and `removeListener` as the interface to this kind of thing.

Comment: @Moo-Juice, in that case you are never going to generate new wrappers for the same function again and so using ints like in my comment above will work great. Just make addListener return the unique identifier and let removeListener take that as an argument.

Comment: Related: [Comparing std::tr1::function<> objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/89488/20984)

Comment: Why do you need to find function that you already have? o_O

Comment: So you want to tag each function in a collection? Why not to use a std::map for that instead of std::vector then?

Comment: I think you should look at the boost signals library... which I believe alrdy implements what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at [Boost Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/signals.html)? It may already be doing what you want to do.

Anyway, a simple way of wrapping the `function` would be to use a `shared_ptr`. If you do

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<std::function<void(int)> > MyFunctionDecl;
```

and make sure that the function is wrapped immediately inside the `shared_ptr` when you create it (so that the pointer is unique), pointers can be tested for equality so `std::find` would work.

For example you can do so with a factory function like

```
template <class Functor>
MyFunctionDecl createDelegate(Functor f) {
    return MyFunctionDecl(new std::function<void(int)>(f));
}
```

This way you give an unique identity to the function (its pointer) when you create the delegate.

BTW, I'd use an `std::set` instead of an `std::vector`, as both `find` and `erase` are logarithmic rather than linear.

Comment: thanks for this.  I have created an implementation given your idea and am in the process of checking it out now.  Have amended my original post to show current code.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Wrapper
{
    private:
       T m_Func;

    public:

       template<typename U>
       bool operator==(const Wrapper<U>& _rhs)
       {
           return boost::is_same<T, U>::value;
       }
};

int main()
{
    Wrapper<int> Wint;
    Wrapper<bool> Wbool;
    std::cout << (Wint == Wbool) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (Wint == Wint) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem. boost::is_same checks for type equality, not object equality.

Comment: But Wrapper has an operator==

Comment: Yes, so do a lot of other classes that do not help either... :)

Comment: What is your problem with this solution?

Comment: It isn't a solution, that's the problem. You can't differentiate between two different Wrapper<std::function<void(int)> > .

Comment: If you want differentiate than ex. you have to use a class for it (typedef void (class::*)(args..)), or select by function overloading

Comment: Could you clarify how you want this to work with lambda functions? Hint: it won't... :)